# What does it mean to define constants in an interface?

Tags: java, interface, constants

I know that in Java, someone can include constants inside interfaces by declaring them `public static final`. However, suppose I have such an interface, called `I`, which contains only public static final constants and no method signatures, and a class called `C`. Why would I want to implement I in C? i.e. why would I do the following:

`public class C implements I`

Since the constants are public and static, wouldn't I be able to access them directly through `I`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This (anti-)pattern is useful because it lets you use the names of those constants without having to prefix them with `I.`.  This used to be a common technique, but now that you can use `import static` to import the constants the same way it's fallen out of favor.  One of the reasons for avoiding it is that the set of constants really isn't an interface - it's just a bunch of values - and making it an interface lets you do bizarre things like writing

```
ConstantInterfaceWithNoMethods m = new ClassImplementingThatInterface;
```

or

```
if (m instanceof ConstantInterfaceWithNoMethods)
```

which just don't make sense in this context.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! I'll accept this answer as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 5):

This is a Java pattern that lets  you access constants from the interface without typing the name of that interface over and over. The pattern has been around since the early days, many years before `enum`s made their way into the language.

Some consider it questionable, because it leads to creating interfaces that do not specify a contract.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't need to. One reason could be, that the interface `I` is a "marker interface".

Comment: It's an interface without any methods.  Not sure how this answer relates to the OP's question, though.

Comment: @NathanSabruka- A marker interface is an interface like `Serializable` that has no methods in it and serves just as a "marker" that a class has some property.  Since the introduction of annotations, they too have fallen out of favor.